# Migrating ms sql data from on premise to azure

Tags: database, database-migration

I have 10TB of ms sql data on premise. I want to migrate the data from on premise to the azure ms sql server without any downtime. Please help me or suggest me how to do that. Is it possible to migrate that much data using the transactional data migration. If is there any other tool to do that please also suggest. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a service where you ship them physical media and they upload it to the azure servers. Probably the best thing to do for such a large dataset.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/import-export/

ps - for future questions, read "[How Do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" first.